# Is Getting started with Django (Django 1.4) tutorial ok for Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django-1.4, django-1.9

Does anyone know if it makes sense to go through this tutorial with django 1.9, even though the tutorial is based on 1.4

Is there an updated version of http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com

Comment: Probably not, just go for a 1.9 tutorial

Comment: No you should either go for django 1.8 or 1.9 things are a lot different between 1.4 & 1.9 and instead of tutorials I'll suggest docs cause no matter what tutorial you go through while development you have to go through django docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for this. Latest, official and the most relevant tutorial.

[Django 1.9 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)